# SQL Select query inside a check constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have these tables

```
student(num int, age int); 

ex(id int, num int);
```

i want to add a constraint when inserting informations in ex to check if the student age is bigger than 20 (No triggers or functions)

This is my attempt

```
ALTER TABLE ex
  ADD CONSTRAINT x_check CHECK((SELECT age FROM student S WHERE num=S.num )>20);
```

But it doesn't work, any solution ?

Comment: I am pretty sure MySQL does not support custom constraints such as that, but we don't use the latest versions of MySQL Server at my workplace, so I can't say that with 100% certainty.

Comment: Yes, MySQL does not support check constraints. So, triggers: yes.

Comment: I don't think such a thing as 'inter-table' level constraint exists in MySQL or any other RDMBS. Constraints, as far as I know, are either column or table level.

Comment: As a bit of hackiness, you could create a `valid_ages` table, with only an int column, and have a foreign key to that.

Comment: It is irrelevant anyway, because MySQL does not enforce check constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that a CHECK is a table-level constraint. You cannot (at least to my knowledge) add a constraint (outside a FK constrain) that runs a select statement against a DIFFERENT table.

The reason for this is simple. If the OTHER table changes (student), then it would NOT enforce integrity on the "ex" table.

So you could do several things, depending on what suits best:

a) Whatever script does the inserts/updates to check if the age is >=20 BEFORE inserting, else it should error

b) Set up a trigger that runs BEFORE insert or update to check this, else fails. But the trigger would have to be set up on BOTH tables in order to maintain table integrity.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is irrelevant anyway because MySQL does not enforce check constraints.  However, you can do something with a foreign key constraint.  You want to ensure that students in `ex` are over 20.

Ideally, you could just change the `student` table to have a column like:

```
alter table student add StudentOver20 as (case when age > 20 then num end);

alter table student add key (StudentOver20);
```

Then, a foreign key to this column would enforce the constraint:

```
alter table ex add foreign key (num) references student(StudentOver20)
```

Unfortunately, in MySQL, you cannot add the column with a value like that.  Instead, you need to update the value:

```
alter table student add StudentOver20 int;

update student set StudentOver20 = (case when age > 20 then num end);
```

If you want to keep it up-to-date, then you need to add a trigger.  Of course, if you are adding a trigger, you might as well add it to `ex` to do the check in the trigger.

Do note that storing `age` in a table is a bad idea.  The values will definitely be incorrect one year from now.

Comment: perhaps your answer could be updated now that MySQL 8 does enforce check constraints?