# Validation of database integrity with Hibernate validator

Tags: java, database, hibernate, validation

Hibernate validator works well for me to validate objects fetched by hibernate, but the problem is that I would like to make sure that certain conditions are met after persisting/updating objects in database. For example:

My condition is: User can host at most 3 games

Constraint annotation:

```
@Target({ FIELD, TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = GamesCountValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ConstrainHostGamesCount {
    String message() default "{com.afrixs.mygameserver.db.constraint.ConstrainHostGamesCount.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Validator:

```
public class GamesCountValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ConstrainHostGamesCount, User> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConstrainHostGamesCount constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(User user, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (user == null)
            return true;
        
        return user.getGames().size() <= 3;
    }
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
@ConstrainHostGamesCount
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=11)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name", length=30, unique=true)
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Game> games = new HashSet<>();

    //generic getters and setters
}
```

Game class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Games")
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=11)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @ConstrainHostGamesCount
    private User user;

    //generic getters and setters
}
```

Test method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void hostGames(String userName, int count) {
        try {
            Session session = DatabaseManager.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            Query userQuery = session.createQuery("from User where name = :name");
            userQuery.setParameter("name", name);
            User user = (User)userQuery.uniqueResult();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Game = new Game();
                game.setUser(user);
                session.persist(game);
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            DatabaseManager.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Desired behavior for `Test.hostGames("afrixs", 4)` would be to fail. However the validator validates the state of the user object before the update, ie. with games.size() equal to 0, so the constraint condition is met and nothing fails until `Test.hostGames("afrixs", 4)` is called for the second time. Of course in this situation we could manually add games to user `user.getGames().add(game)` but this attitude is error prone (the game needs to be added to user this way everywhere in the code) and it doesn't solve the problem if for example two `Test.hostGames("afrixs", 2)` are called asynchronously.

So my question is: what is the proper way of constraining the database integrity using hibernate? Is there a way to make the validator check the final state of objects after storing them into database? Or do I need to do the constraining manually (like performing another transaction after `session.getTransaction().commit` and check the conditions and roll back the updating transaction if they are not met)? Or should I leave out hibernate and use SQL triggers for this? Thank you for your answers, they will help a lot

And here is my current hibernate validation configuration:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist">javax.validation.groups.Default</property>
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update">javax.validation.groups.Default</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

Comment: You need to add the constraints you want to your database schema.

Comment: In my experience bidirectional relations better be updated on both ends at the same time (so call `user.getGames().add(game)`) otherwise the model is not in a consistent state and this could break elsewhere. For instance your code breaks if `games` becomes a `List` (what is the index of the new game?) Adding a `User#addGame()` method updating both would help

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I think I will try both attitudes out and add/compare the results as an answer. @OrangeDog Just one noob question to be sure: database schema means how my tables are created in SQL, right? So I will need to add CHECK constraints or in the case of inter-table constraints triggers before insert/update/delete ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/30385684/4003774 ) if I understand it well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have made some experiments, writing down a small test class. To make things simple I changed the constraint to "User can host at most 1 game".

```
public class DBTest {
    @Test
    public void gamesCountConstraintWorking() {
        DBManager.deleteHostedGames("afrixs");
        boolean ok1 = DBManager.createOneGame("afrixs");
        boolean ok2 = DBManager.createOneGame("afrixs");
        int gamesCount = DBManager.deleteHostedGames("afrixs");
        System.out.println("Sync test: count: "+gamesCount+", ok1: "+ok1+", ok2: "+ok2);
        assertTrue(gamesCount <= 1);
        assertTrue(!(ok1 && ok2));
    }

    @Test
    public void gamesCountConstraintWorkingAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        DBManager.deleteHostedGames("afrixs");
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            CreateOneGameRunnable r1 = new CreateOneGameRunnable(1);
            CreateOneGameRunnable r2 = new CreateOneGameRunnable(2);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            int maxCount = 0;
            while (r1.running || r2.running) {
                int count = DBManager.selectHostedGamesCount("afrixs");
                System.out.println("count: "+count);
                maxCount = Math.max(maxCount, count);
            }
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            int gamesCount = DBManager.deleteHostedGames("afrixs");
            System.out.println("Async test: count: "+gamesCount+", maxCount: "+maxCount+", ok1: "+r1.ok+", ok2: "+r2.ok);
            assertTrue(maxCount <= 1 && gamesCount <= 1);
            assertTrue(!(r1.ok && r2.ok));
        }
    }

    private class CreateOneGameRunnable implements Runnable {
        public boolean ok;
        public boolean running = true;
        private int number;
        CreateOneGameRunnable(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting "+number);
            ok = DBManager.createOneGame("afrixs");
            System.out.println("Finished "+number);
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

First I tried out @Guillaume's suggestion to use `user.getGames().add(game);` along with `game.setUser(user);` when assigning the relation. `gamesCountConstraintWorking` test was successful, however, `gamesCountConstraintWorkingAsync` wasn't. It means that this attitude was successful in maintaining the session consistency (at the cost of fetching all user games), however, the database integrity wasn't maintained.

A solution that actually worked for both tests was (as @OrangeDog suggested) to add the constraint directly into database schema. MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER check_user_games_count
AFTER INSERT
ON Games FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE gamesCount INT;
    SET gamesCount = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Games WHERE user_id = new.user_id);
    IF gamesCount > 1 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'User may host at most 1 game';
    END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

So my summary is that Hibernate works great as a layer above the database to work with, but if you want to make sure the persisted data look like you want, you need to dive directly into your database schema and perform actions in there. (But that's only the result of this experiment, maybe someone knows a solution for this using Hibernate)

Note: I tried the tests with BEFORE UPDATE triggers and random delays inside the triggers and the tests were successful as well, it seems like some kind of lock is acquired for the table while inserting, so yes, this is a safe solution. (Note2: BEFORE UPDATE trigger for this needs gamesCount+1 > 1 condition and the constraint could fail (not tested) in the case of inserting multiple rows in one query)